# Detect manual Bluetooth disabling

Tags: android, bluetooth

my Android application have to catch the MANUAL disabling of the bluetooth to avoid a fraud. I am using the following code and some of the users told me that any bluetooth error fires the `btTurnedOff()`.

Listener...

```
public interface BtConnectionListener {

    void btTurnedOff();
}
```

Receiver...

```
public class BtConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final BtConnectionListener listener;

public BtConnectionReceiver(final BtConnectionListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action != null && action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
        switch (state) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                listener.btTurnedOff();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my main service...

```
@Override
public void btTurnedOff() {
    //Some stuff to penalize the fraud
}
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you defined the permissions in the manifest and when & where you register this broadcast?

Comment: I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> in my manifest and I have defined the register in the onCreate() of the service

Comment: try to register your broadcast in manifest only